# Google Autofill API

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

I followed this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) to fill the city on the basis of address automatically.

But when I tried to implement it, I am not getting the functionality I want. I want that after filling the address the city field should automatically be filled. Below is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">City</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
<input type="text" id="crack" name="City" class="form-control"  >
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Area</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
<input type="text" id="ar" name="Area" class="form-control"  >
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-   input">Address</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
 <input type="text" id="add" name="Address" class="form-control"  >
</div>
</div>
```

Below is the javascript code

```
  <script>
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#crack")[0], {});

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(place.address_components);
        });
    </script>
     <script>
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#add")[0], {});

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                console.log(place.address_components);
            });
                        var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
    crack: 'long_name',
};

            function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
        </script>

<?php include 'inc/template_end.php'; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hi()
{
    var ele=(document.getElementById("sla").value);
    if(ele==1)
    {
        document.getElementById("g1").style.display="none";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("g1").style.display = "initial";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Was my answer any help to you @Legendary_Hunter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it was not populating was due to the `input` tag `id`s you used: `id="crack"`, `id="ar"`, & `id="add"`. Google uses `id="locality"`, `id="administrative_area_level_1"`, & `id="route"` respectively.

Not to mention they return several more fields of information, so without `input` tags to receive them, you would receive errors from that as well.

So with some mapping of your `input` tag `id`s in the `fillInAddress()` function, as well as putting in a catch for any other returned fields, we are able to accomplish population of the fields as you had hoped:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">City</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" id="crack" name="City" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Area</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" id="ar" name="Area" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-   input">Address</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" id="add" name="Address" onFocus="geolocate()" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

    function initialize(){
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            (document.getElementById('add')),
            {
                types: ['geocode']
            }
        );

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(){
            fillInAddress();
        });
    }

    function fillInAddress(){
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                input = 1;
                if (addressType === 'street_number') addressType = 'add';
                else if (addressType === 'route'){
                    addressType = 'add';
                    val = document.getElementById(addressType).value + ' ' + val;
                } else if (addressType === 'locality') addressType = 'crack';
                else if (addressType === 'administrative_area_level_1') addressType = 'ar';
                else input = 0;
                if (input) document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
            }
        }
    }

    function geolocate(){
        if (navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    position.coords.latitude,
                    position.coords.longitude
                );
                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: geolocation,
                    radius: position.coords.accuracy
                });
                autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
            });
        }
    }

    initialize();
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7t1p6oL1/